# Detach event with detachPageDataLoaded

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I need to detach an event handler that was attached with the following code:

```js
var oNavController = this.getOwnerComponent().getAppComponent().getNavigationController();
this.extensionAPI.attachPageDataLoaded(this._executeTrampolin.bind(this, oNavController));
```

[API reference: `attachPageDataLoaded`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ObjectPage.extensionAPI.ExtensionAPI%23methods/attachPageDataLoaded)

This is standard code, I don't want to change it.
So I'm trying to remove this event from an extension, with the following code:

```js
var that = this.base.getView().getController();
var oNavController = that.getOwnerComponent().getAppComponent().getNavigationController();
that.extensionAPI.detachPageDataLoaded(that._executeTrampolin.bind(that, oNavController));
```

But the event is not getting detached.

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61589257/5846045 It's a common mistake to call `.bind(this)` whenever attaching an event handler in UI5. It's impossible to detach the handler since `bind` creates always a new function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly attach and detach event handler in UI5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61589257/how-to-properly-attach-and-detach-event-handler-in-ui5)